# Who restarted my Windows server?

Tags: windows, logging, log-files, boot, windows-event-log

Is it possible on Windows Server 2000/2003/2008 machines to see which user rebooted the server?

I have found the shutdown event in the System event log, but it does not show which user initiated the reboot.

Comment: [Who took the cookie from the cookie jar?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Stole_the_Cookie_from_the_Cookie_Jar%3F)

Comment: [Who's on first?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sShMA85pv8M)

Comment: No, *What* rebooted the server. *Who* installed the malware.

Comment: Was more than one person logged in at the time?

Comment: So who was it that restarted the server?

Comment: As I said, it was Who.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In the `System` event log, filter by event id `1074`, this will show by which process and on behalf of which user a reboot was initiated.

This was tested on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Also works on Windows Server 2003 (SP 2)

Answer (score 5):

There should be a log at:

```
%windir%\system32\LogFiles\Shutdown
```

(which should be `C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\Shutdown` on a "standard" Windows Server 2000/2003 install)

Comment: That folder does not exist on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: well you did specify for 2000/2003 as well :)

Comment: I give you that!